# Cycles or selection operators in the template_file

Tags: templates, terraform, operation

Ran into a problem like this. I can 't figure out how to create a temlate_file of this kind:

`[master]
ser1 ansible_host=10.0.0.1
ser2 ansible_host=10.0.0.2`

So that the name and address are generated from the change.
I use standard costruction in date.tf:

```
data "template_file" "inventory" {
count = length(var.domains)
template = file("inventory.tpl")
vars = {
master_ip = join("\n", hcloud_server.rebrain_quest.*.ipv4_address)
key_path = var.privat_key
}
}
```

But here I can only generate my address.

`[master]
10.0.0.1
10.0.0.2`

You may need some way like that, but I don 't have anything coming out:

```
master_ip = join(";", [hcloud_server.rebrain_quest.*.name, ansible_host=, hcloud_server.rebrain_quest.*.ipv4_address])
```

I have terraform version v0.12.24

Answer (score 1):

Because you are using Terraform 0.12, you should use [the `templatefile` function](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions/templatefile.html) instead of the `template_file` data source. Because it's built into the language rather than being offered by a provider, it's free of the data source's limitations like forcing all of the `vars` values to be strings.

```
locals {
  ansible_inventory = templatefile("${path.module}/inventory.tpl", {
    hosts = hcloud_server.rebrain_quest
  })
}
```

Then in the template file:

```
[master]
%{ for h in hosts ~}
${h.name} ansible_host=${h.ipv4_address}
%{ endfor ~}
```

The above template is a variation of the example given in [the documentation about Terraform's template directive syntax](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/expressions.html#directives).

---

Your original example included `count = var.domains` but the rest of the resource configuration didn't include any mention of `count.index` so I assumed that wasn't actually needed. However, if you do want to create multiple copies of the template based on the number in `var.domains` you can do with the following variation:

```
locals {
  ansible_inventory = [
    for i in range(var.domains) :
    templatefile("${path.module}/inventory.tpl", {
      hosts = hcloud_server.rebrain_quest
      index = i
    })
  ]
}
```

[The `range` function](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions/range.html) here creates a list of integers from zero to `var.domains - 1`, and so we can use that with `for` to repeat the template rendering multiple times. I added `index = i` to the template variables object so that you could in principle use `${i}` inside the template to get a similar effect as with `count.index` in a resource block.

Answer (score 0):

Terraform:

```
data "template_file" "inventory" {
  count    = length(var.domains)
  template = file("inventory.tpl")

  vars = {
    hosts = hcloud_server.rebrain_quest
    lines = [
      for h in hcloud_server.rebrain_quest:
    ]
  }
}
```

Template:

```
[master]
%{ for h in hosts ~}
${h.name} ansible_host=${h.ipv4_address}
%{ endfor ~}
```

But consider using terraform-ansible (there are bunch of them), use [hcloud dynamic inventory plugin](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/inventory/hcloud.html) or use ad-hoc hcloud discover via [hcloud_server_info](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/hcloud_server_info_module.html)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for the answers, I solved this problem with a complex expression:

```
master_ip = "${join("\n", [for instance in hcloud_server.rebrain_quest : join("", [instance.name, " ansible_host=", instance.ipv4_address])] )}"
```